# OCaml converting functional arrays as binary tree to list

Tags: arrays, list, tree, ocaml

I have to convert a functional array to a list on OCaml and this is what I have so far but it isn't passing the tests, can anyone help with what's wrong with my code and what method I should use instead?

I first wrote a function to return the tree except for the first value, then take the heads and cons it to the heads of the rest to create a list. Have I made a mistake?

```
exception Subscript

let top = function
  | Lf -> raise Subscript
  | Br (v,_,_) -> v

let rec pop = function
  | Lf -> raise Subscript
  | Br (_, Lf, Lf) -> Lf
  | Br (_, lt, rt) -> Br (top lt, rt, pop lt)

let rec listofarray = function
  | Br (v, t1, t2) -> v :: (listofarray (pop (Br(v, t1, t2))))
  | Lf -> []
```

Comment: Knowing which tests failed would be very valuable.

Comment: It might be helpful to include the definition of your tree data type. I can infer it to be something like `type 'a tree = Lf | Br of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree` but including it in your question wouldn't make the code example onerously longer.

Answer (score 2):

As Jeffrey Scofield has suggested, you may wish to modify your implementation of `pop` to handle situations where the left tree or right tree are `Lf` but not *both*.

```
let rec pop = function
  | Lf -> raise Subscript
  | Br (_, Lf, Lf) -> Lf
  | Br (_, Lf, rt) -> ...
  | Br (_, lt, Lf) -> ...
  | Br (_, lt, rt) -> Br (top lt, rt, pop lt)
```

Now the question is what `pop` should do in each of those cases.  Consider the first scenario.

```
   0
  / \
 /   \
Lf    1
     / \
    /   \
   Lf   Lf
```

It seems fairly obvious that after `pop` we should have:

```
   1
  / \
 /   \
Lf   Lf
```

We can get this by simply returning the right tree.

```
let rec pop = function
  | Lf -> raise Subscript
  | Br (_, Lf, Lf) -> Lf
  | Br (_, Lf, rt) -> rt
  | Br (_, lt, Lf) -> ...
  | Br (_, lt, rt) -> Br (top lt, rt, pop lt)
```

Likewise, if we consider the other scenario, we can see that the solution will be just as simple.

```
         0              1
        / \            / \ 
       /   \          /   \
      1    Lf   ->   Lf   Lf
     / \
    /   \
   Lf   Lf
```

We can implement this by just returning the left tree.

```
let rec pop = function
  | Lf -> raise Subscript
  | Br (_, Lf, Lf) -> Lf
  | Br (_, Lf, rt) -> rt
  | Br (_, lt, Lf) -> lt
  | Br (_, lt, rt) -> Br (top lt, rt, pop lt)
```

Now, without changing `listofarray` we do get a correct result when evaluating the example Jeffrey Scofield provided.

```
utop # listofarray (Br (0, Lf, Br (1, Lf, Lf)));;
- : int list = [0; 1]
utop # listofarray (Br (0, Br (1, Lf, Lf), Lf));;
- : int list = [0; 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't say whether the trees have extra invariants. Unless there are limits on the possible trees, your `pop` function doesn't work for all of them:

```
# pop (Br (0, Br (1, Lf, Lf), Lf));;
- : tree = Br (1, Lf, Lf)
# pop (Br (0, Lf, Br (1, Lf, Lf)));;
Exception: Subscript.
```